# How to reduce history_uint table size in Zabbix database server?

Tags: zabbix

I have a problem that my Zabbix Database server's `history_uint` table is too long. It takes 57GB space. For that reason, the query takes much more time to execute.

How could I reduce the space and make my query faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the table name suggest, it's where the history values of integer data types are stored.

The only way to have a smaller table is to store less history.

The history values do store each item value as it is retrieved/received from the hosts.
The are stored as long as the history storage period is defined.
The housekeeping then removes these values from the history tables when it is running.

So either do less frequent data aquisition in your items and/or reduce the time the history is stored.

Also make sure, that the housekeeping is running and configured correctly.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/history_and_trends

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/installation/requirements#database_size

Comment: but my table contains only three months data. For that reason i need all the data.

Comment: There are the trends data too which might cover what you need. Please Is your housekeeping running?

Comment: ５values @Andre Schild

Comment: Are you sure? With 5 nv per second you don't would have this size of database. When you do a db dump, is the sql file also that big?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with the size of the DB is to implement partitioning (see [here](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/mysql_partition) and [here](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/MySQL_Table_Partitioning_(variant))) and to use innodb with `innodb_file_per_table = 1`.

You will have a single file per partition, with a daily rotation which will delete old partitions and free up some space.

This setup *could* solve some performance problems when accessing the history, but it also depends on the retention times of your items, the number of items, the database server's load and underlying disks etc.